# Share axis and remove unused in matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a series of seaborn heatmaps in a grid. I know the number of subplots (which can be odd or even).
The heatmaps will show the mean "occupation ratio" by "day of week" (y axis) and "hour of day" (x axis), e.g. they all share the same x / y domains.

Here's my current code:

```
df2 = df[['name','openLots','occupationRatio','DoW','Hour']]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(24,24), nrows=7, ncols=6)
axs = axs.flatten()
locations = df2['name'].sort_values().unique()


def occupation_heatmap (name, ax):
    dfn = df2[df2['name'] == name]
    dfn = dfn.groupby(['DoW', 'Hour']).mean()['occupationRatio'].unstack()
    dfn = dfn.reindex(['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'])
    sns.heatmap(data=dfn, cmap="coolwarm", vmin=0, vmax=1.0, ax= ax)
    ax.set_title(name)


i = 0
for n in locations: 
    occupation_heatmap (n, axs[i])
    i = i+1

plt.tight_layout()
```

It looks *almost* like what I want (last few rows):
[image: note axis labels, legend and "empty" subplots]
However want I want:

- Have the y axis labels (DoW) only once per row (leftmost plot)
- Have the colormap legend only on the rightmost plot in each row (or leave it out completely, the colors are pretty self-explainatory)
- remove the "empty plots" in the last row because of an odd total number

Many thanks for any hints

Comment: Just to help improve your mental model of how things are working, these aren't "seaborn subplots", they are matplotlib subplots that you happen to be using seaborn functions to plot data on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be more flexible and just create an axis for each name present, something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import string

days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun']
names = [string.lowercase[i] for i in range(22)]

nItems = 1000

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = [names[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,len(names),nItems)]
df['openLots'] = np.random.randint(0,100,nItems)
df['occupationRatio'] = np.random.randint(0,100,nItems)
df['DoW'] = [days[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,7,nItems)]
df['Hour'] = np.random.randint(0,12,nItems)




fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
for index, name in enumerate(names):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,6,index+1)
    dfn = df.loc[df.name==name]
    dfn = dfn.groupby(['DoW','Hour']).mean()['occupationRatio'].unstack()
    dfn = dfn.reindex(days)

    # Now we can operate on each plot axis individually
    if index%6!=5: #i.e.
        # Don't draw a colorbar
        sns.heatmap(data = dfn, cmap='coolwarm', ax=ax, cbar=False)
    else:
        sns.heatmap(data = dfn, cmap='coolwarm', ax=ax)

    if index%6!=0:
        # Remove the y-axis label
        ax.set_ylabel('')
        ax.set_yticks(())

    ax.set_title(name)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Results in:
[image]
You could also play around with the x-axes (for example remove labels and ticks except for the bottom row).

Comment: thanks, this workes very well for me...except I had some data slices which were full NaN, so had to wrap sns.heatmap(...) into  
`try:    
   ...
except ValueError: 
        pass
`

Answer (score 4):

- *Have the y axis labels (DoW) only once per row (leftmost plot)*
  This can be done using `sharey = True` as argument to `plt.subplots`.
- *Have the colormap legend only on the rightmost plot in each row (or leave it out completely, the colors are pretty self-explainatory)*
  Use the `cbar = False` argument to `seaborn.heatmap` in order not to show a colorbar. This can be given as an input to the plotting function in dependence of the actual number of subplots.
- *remove the "empty plots" in the last row because of an odd total number*
  After the loop for creating the plots you may add another loop removing the unused axes.

  ```
  for j in range(len(locations), ncols*nrows):
      axs[j].axis("off")
  ```

Here is a complete example (where I borrowed the cod to generate a dataframe from @Robbie):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun']
names = ["Parkhaus {:02}".format(i+1) for i in range(22)]

nItems = 1000

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = [names[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,len(names),nItems)]
df['openLots'] = np.random.randint(0,100,nItems)
df['occupationRatio'] = np.random.rand(nItems)
df['DoW'] = [days[i] for i in np.random.randint(0,7,nItems)]
df['Hour'] = np.random.randint(0,12,nItems)

df2 = df[['name','openLots','occupationRatio','DoW','Hour']]
nrows = 4; ncols=6
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(15,9), sharey=True)
axs = axs.flatten()
locations = df2['name'].sort_values().unique()


def occupation_heatmap (name, ax, cbar=False, ylabel=False):
    dfn = df2[df2['name'] == name]
    dfn = dfn.groupby(['DoW', 'Hour']).mean()['occupationRatio'].unstack()
    dfn = dfn.reindex(['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'])
    sns.heatmap(data=dfn, cmap="coolwarm", vmin=0, vmax=1.0, ax=ax, cbar=cbar)
    ax.set_title(name)
    plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)
    if not ylabel: ax.set_ylabel("")


for i, n in enumerate(locations): 
    occupation_heatmap (n, axs[i], cbar=i%ncols==ncols-1, ylabel=i%ncols==0)
for j in range(len(locations), ncols*nrows):
    axs[j].axis("off")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]